# What is the distribution of /dev/urandom? Code to verify?

Tags: linux, bash, random

Everywhere I look it says `/dev/urandom` on linux is "random", but no source I can find cites what kind of random "random" is. My hope is that it is close to uniform on 0x01 to 0xff bytewise. If I wanted to test this, what would be the best way to get an estimate of the distribution? Solution in `bash` preferred.

Comment: You don't want any 0 bytes? (I think the expectation of uniform distribution over the range from **0** to 0xff is so obvious that nobody bothers to write it down)

Comment: Isn't a 0 byte EOF? When I `cat /dev/urandom` is doesn't stop on its own so that means there are no zero bytes, right? 0 to 0xff would be even better. The question remains though, is the distribution supposed to be uniform (each byte equally likely)? Or something else?

Comment: I seem to be getting quite a bit of hate for this question. Could someone at least comment on why the downvotes?

Comment: A simple test (like counting how many times an output appears for a million runs) is only good for very simple PRNG. A somewhat better group of tests (in the 10^10 order of runs, and several statistical tests) is provided by [dieharder](https://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php). But that is only the "common tests" for a CSPRNG. Understand that a correct CSPRNG requires **a lot** of *peer* review. ... ... ... Bottom line: do not believe that bash `$RANDOM` is a valid CSPRNG in any way, shape or form. It is believed (until proved false) that urandom is secure. ... ... (Cont.)

Comment: The [Linux kernel uses SHA1](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/char/random.c?id=refs/tags/v3.15.6#n1017) And it [has been analized in detail many times](https://pthree.org/2014/07/21/the-linux-random-number-generator/). And even [Wikipedia has a reasonable page on the issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) which also reports:[In October 2016, Linux kernel version 4.8 and newer, /dev/urandom switched to ChaCha20](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=818e607b57c94ade9824dad63a96c2ea6b21baf3)

Comment: In short: `/dev/urandom/` is as good as we know how to make CSPRNG's, just trust it, Please!.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` are kernel devices. Check the man pages or the kernel docs.

Comment: @jww did you read the question? or the answers? if you did you would realize this is a programming question. also, if you read the man pages or kernel docs you would know it does not specify the intended distribution of the output. The closest thing it says in the man page or docs is that it is supposed to be a CSPRNG. But with respect to what distribution? It doesn't say.

Comment: @nullUser - Yes, I read it. Here was your question: *"If I wanted to test this, what would be the best way to get an estimate of the distribution"*. That's not a programming or development question. There are better sites for the question. The man pages and kernel docs provided you with the answer to your trouble with: *"no source I can find cites what kind of random "random" ..."*. That is, you were told where to look. And I am kind of surprised it was not closed for the *"[Give me the] code to verify"* in the title. Usually that gets jumped on for the code writing service thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Python program that shows it is pretty darned uniform (at least on macOS):

```
import os
cnt, start=[10000000]*2
buckets={}
while cnt:
    c=os.urandom(1)
    buckets.setdefault(c, 0)
    buckets[c]+=1
    cnt-=1

ideal=1/256.0
if len(buckets) != 256: print('{} missing keys'.format(256-len(buckets)))
for k, v in sorted(buckets.items()):
    actual=float(buckets[k])/start
    print('{:8} {:10.4%} {:10.4%}'.format(repr(k), actual, actual-ideal ))
```

Prints:

```
b'\x00'     0.3892%   -0.0014%
b'\x01'     0.3950%    0.0044%
b'\x02'     0.3856%   -0.0050%
b'\x03'     0.3901%   -0.0006%
b'\x04'     0.3894%   -0.0013%
b'\x05'     0.3881%   -0.0025%
b'\x06'     0.3912%    0.0006%
b'\x07'     0.3912%    0.0005%
b'\x08'     0.3951%    0.0044%
b'\t'       0.3928%    0.0022%
b'\n'       0.3877%   -0.0029%
...
b'\xf7'     0.3914%    0.0008%
b'\xf8'     0.3906%   -0.0001%
b'\xf9'     0.3917%    0.0011%
b'\xfa'     0.3910%    0.0004%
b'\xfb'     0.3884%   -0.0022%
b'\xfc'     0.3915%    0.0009%
b'\xfd'     0.3904%   -0.0002%
b'\xfe'     0.3894%   -0.0013%
b'\xff'     0.3914%    0.0008%
```

Comment: That `x08` looks a bit dodgy to me 

Comment: [Please read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945941/what-is-the-distribution-of-dev-urandom-code-to-verify#comment71075926_41945941).

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

```
cat /dev/urandom | hexdump -n 100000000 -v -e '/1 "0x%02X\n"' | sort -n | uniq -c | awk '{print $1/100000000"\t"$2;}'
```

works well enough.

Also RFC 1750: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1750. The output is not uniform, but its goal is to be close.